# PHP what does ord() stand for?

Tags: php, ord

I just really want to know what ord() stands for, like what it is an abbreviation for. I know what it does, I'm just really curious what it means written out, like how I'm assuming that the opposite, chr(), probably stands for char.

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) of any use to you?

Comment: @Granny unfortunately not! It explains what ord() does, but not what the name stands for :( Thank you, though.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php is probably better

Comment: The link provided by @Granny would be useful if the OP were interested in ord() with reference to Python, but the OP is asking how it relates to PHP which is different; see http://php.net/ord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "ordinal".

Ordinal numbers are counting numbers